# Preload sound AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, swc, preloading

I have AS3 project, made with FlashBuilder. I'm using MovieClips from an external .SWC-file.
In a MovieClip from the .SWF-file, I want to use an audio-file.

Is it possible to preload a sound-file (e.g. .MP3) in my FlashBuilder project, and access it in a MovieClip inside the .SWC?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: can you edit your .swc ?

Comment: yes, I made it with the Flash IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I don't know hoe you create your swc's but I'll tell you my setup which always works.

I create an asset FLA which would have the mp3 among other things.
I compile using FlashDevelop, and use the preloader template. Never had problems with that.

What you can't do is use SWCs run-time.